# jQuery - Changing Images on Click (Simplifying Functions)

Tags: jquery, image, getelementbyid

I created a mini demo for changing images on click. Thought I can get some feedback to see how I can minize/clean up the code. Don't mind the image sizes, they're FPO. There is also a slight lag on image load. How can I integrate a preloader into this example?

I don't think this is the best solution to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish. Anyone have any similar resources to point me to?

http://jsfiddle.net/mJ7Wc/

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#wheel1').click (function () {
        document.getElementById('changeBack').src='http://placehold.it/50x50';
        document.getElementById('changeFront').src='http://placehold.it/50x50';
    });
    $('#wheel2').click (function () {
        document.getElementById('changeBack').src='http://placehold.it/30x30';
        document.getElementById('changeFront').src='http://placehold.it/30x30';
    });
 $('#wheel3').click (function () {
        document.getElementById('changeBack').src='http://placehold.it/60x60';
     document.getElementById('changeFront').src='http://placehold.it/60x60';
    });
    $('#wheel4').click (function () {
        document.getElementById('changeBack').src='http://placehold.it/80x80';
        document.getElementById('changeFront').src='http://placehold.it/80x80';
    });
});
```

Comment: How about actually using jQuery, that should shorten it down a bit for you.

Comment: Here's a cleaned up version for a start: http://jsfiddle.net/mJ7Wc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options for you.

#### 1. Use a map:

*(See notes below.)*

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var images = {
        wheel1: {
            front: 'http://placehold.it/50x50',
            back:  'http://placehold.it/50x50'
        },
        wheel2: {
            front: 'http://placehold.it/30x30',
            back:  'http://placehold.it/30x30'
        },
        wheel3: {
            front: 'http://placehold.it/60x60',
            back:  'http://placehold.it/60x60'
        },
        wheel4: {
            front: 'http://placehold.it/80x80',
            back:  'http://placehold.it/80x80'
        }
    };

    $(".wheels").click(function() {
        var entry = images[this.id];
        if (entry) {
            $('#changeFront')[0].src = entry.front;
            $('#changeBack')[0].src  = entry.back;
        }
    }
});
```

Two notes on that:

1. I've done the more complex thing of using separate images for front and back, just in case that's what you meant; not immediately seeing why we'd want to repeat the same image twice. If you really want to use the same image twice, just make the `wheelX` entry the actual path rather than an object with `front` and `back`.
2. I've included the full path in case it varies. If it doesn't vary, of course move the invariant bit into the function and just include the `50x50` or whatever in the map.

#### 2. Use `data-*` attributes on the elements.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $(".wheels").click(function() {
        var $this = (this);
        $('#changeFront')[0].src = $this.attr("data-front");
        $('#changeBack')[0].src  = $this.attr("data-back");
    }
});
```

...where your wheels specify the images in the markup:

```
<div id="wheel1" class="wheels" data-front="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-back="http://placehold.it/50x50">
```

...and the same two notes from above apply to this.

Comment: Thank you for your help T.J. Option 2 seems to work well. Similar to the example provided by techfoobar http://jsfiddle.net/mJ7Wc/1

Comment: @user1541063: Great minds think alike. :-) I like the markup-driven approach because adding more wheels happens all in one place (and can be done by your web design staff rather than programming staff, if you have a large shop where those are separate).